# Receive already prepared statement from Cassandra

Tags: python, cassandra, prepared-statement, datastax

I'm not completely shure I get the concepts of prepared statements right, but according to the [python driver docs](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/query.html#cassandra.query.PreparedStatement) a prepared statement is `"A statement that has been prepared against at least one Cassandra node"`. To me that reads that somewhere in the cluster there is information on what queries have already been prepared.The [documentation](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/query.html#cassandra.query.PreparedStatement) furthermore states that `"A PreparedStatement should be prepared only once. Re-preparing a statement may affect performance (as the operation requires a network roundtrip)."`.

If I get the concept right it would be beneficial to receive already prepared statements from the cluster instead of repeatedly regenerating them(1). Is there a way to do so? And if yes, how do I only receive statements I am interested in?

(1)I'm not talking about the scope of one instance of a programm, but multiple instances without shared memory executing the same queries.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct: each node in the cluster caches prepared statements. However, there is no mechanism for obtaining already-prepared statements in the client. There are a number of reasons for this that I won't expound upon here.

Your application your prepare a statement once and keep it around for the lifetime of the cluster/session. The drivers handle things like preparing the statement on all nodes, and re-preparing on nodes that lose them due to cache eviction or restarts.

Comment: I thought so, but thanks for the confirmation. Do you know whether cassandra actually prepares the statement again or just ignores the attempt, but returns a valid prepared statement object? This would be the behaviour I would expect to happen if the cache for prepared statements should stay minimal.